# Failing to create /dev entry from sysfs, No such device or address

Tags: linux, devices, sysfs

I've got some sort of home entertainment system running an old version of Linux 2.6. It has a SATA > USB bridge system and a couple of USB ports. What I want to do is use it as Network Attached Storage.

Now, luckily, it has an open and accessible telnet server running.

The problem is, I can't find where the kernel, nor the init system are. The box is running BusyBox.

The board has a single flash chip on it. But, under sysfs in block/ I see multiple flash chips:

```
/sys/block # ls
...
mtdblock0  mtdblock2  mtdblock4
mtdblock1  mtdblock3
```

Why is that btw?

Now, I want to create a `/dev` entry for them so I can dump each of them to a USB flash drive and analyze them.

So I did this:

```
/sys/block # cat /sys/block/mtdblock0/dev
31:0
```

And ..

```
mknod /dev/mtdblock0 c 31 0
```

Which exited with 0, then I try to read raw data to test the device:

```
/sys/block # cat /dev/mtdblock0 
cat: /dev/mtdblock0: No such device or address
```

Why is that? dd is saying the same. There is entries in `/proc/devices`:

```
/sys/block # cat /proc/devices 
Character devices:
  1 mem

{ ... }

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
  7 loop
  8 sd
 31 mtdblock

{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mknod /dev/mtdblock0 c 31 0
> ```

You created a character device. You wanted a block device. So use `b` instead of `c` in the `mknod` command.

Block device numbers and character device numbers are independent. Block device 31:0 is unrelated to character device 31:0. Your kernel has no driver for character device 31:0, hence the “No such device or address” error.